# Python 3.8: strange behavior of try code block inside while loop

Tags: while-loop, window, try-except, python-3.8

I have the following Python function:

```
def bet():
  my_bet = -1
  while my_bet < 0 or my_bet > 49:
    print("before input")
    my_bet = input("Enter a bet: ")
    print("after input")
    try:
        my_bet = int(my_bet)
        if my_bet < 0 or my_bet > 49:
            print("Bet must be between 0 and 49")
    except:
        print("Need a number between 0 and 49")
        continue
    return my_bet
```

When I run this under Windows 10, I am seeing the following behavior:

```
>>> bet()
before input
enter a bet: ddd
after input
need a number between 0 and 49
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in bet
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

I have also tried moving the if statement after the conversion to int into the else clause of the try statement, with the exact same result. It looks like the conversion is run, raises the exception, then the except block is run, but instead of continuing the loop, it executes the rest of the 'try' code block. According to the Python description, I would not expect the rest of the try block after the exception is raised. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's not running the rest of the `try` code it's going back up to the top of the while loop.

Comment: You can see that it's referencing line 3 of the `bet()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Vorspring durch Technik for pointing out what should have been obvious: after the continue, what is executed is the test of the while loop which is the same as that of the if statement.